# counting specific block labelled

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to count the number of the "1" blocks in a dataframe based on the LabelID attribute. For example, given the following dataframe:

DF input:

```
   eventTime                 velocity     LabelId
1  2017-08-19 12:53:55.050         3        0
2  2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1
3  2017-08-19 12:53:55.150       180        1
4  2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1
5  2017-08-19 12:53:55.250         5        0
6  2017-08-19 12:53:55.050         3        0
7  2017-08-19 12:53:55.100         4        1
8  2017-08-19 12:53:55.150        70        1
9  2017-08-19 12:53:55.200         2        1
10 2017-08-19 12:53:55.250         5        0
```

`Output=2` as it has two blocks of 1. `Block_1=rows 2-4` and `Block_2=rows 7-9`.
Please any help would be very appreciated.

Best Regards, 
Carlo

Comment: A "block" of ones is just any uninterrupted sequence of ones of any size, from a single one to e.g. a thousand of them?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html).  Something like this:

```
d = df.LabelId.diff()
d.iloc[0] = df.LabelId.iloc[0]
```

That gives you:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1]
```

The number of groups of ones is the number of times the diff is 1.  So:

```
(d == 1).sum()
```

Gives you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple way:

```
INTERESTING_LABEL = 1
df = ...  # Make data frame
# Find positions where the label is not present
s = (df.LabelId != INTERESTING_LABEL)
# Counter that increases where the label is not present
# Then select where the label is present and count unique values
num_blocks = s.cumsum()[~s].nunique()
```